# Canvas и проблемы с globalCompositeOperation: как правильно использовать?

Tags: веб-программирование, canvas, javascript, html5, css

**Суть проблемы**: на тестовой версии сайта имеется довольно крупное изображение во всю ширину страницы, заменяющие фон верхней части сайта, *это так по макету;)* нижняя часть изображения должна **плавно** переходить в фон сайта, заданный через **background**, это не все: изображение также должно плавно переливаться **в новое**, по истечению определенного отрезка времени (сервер по запросу рандомно выдает **src** к следующему изображению, всего их **более 100**, поэтому загрузить их всех сразу, как минимум проблематично).

Пробовал делать на одном **div'e** и вложенном **img**: переводил **img** в **base64** формат, и отправлял все это дело в **background div'a** (так как возможно, что у кого-то отключено кеширование *(what?!?!?)*, и плюс это решение проблемы с отсутствием события загрузки для **background'a**), потом скрывал **img**, загружал в него новую картинку, после ее загрузки, с помощью **css** плавно проявлял изображение, и так по кругу. С трудом вериться, но все это прекрасно работало. Только **не везде** и **медленно**. Особенно на **огнелисе**, там для плавного перехода использовались **SVG фильтры**.

Еще пару дней поэкспериментировав с количеством слоев, изображении и перебором разных костылей, я отчаялся и уже хотел просить помощи у **Flash**-программистов, как вспомнил о **HTML5** и пресловутом элементе **Сanvas**, и тут мои молитвы были услышаны: все работает быстрее чем я ожидал, и даже в **IE10!** *;)* Но порывы радости окончились на попытке сделать плавный переход изображения в фон сайта, поэтому я сейчас обращаюсь к Вам, уважаемые **ХэшКодовцы.**

Дело в том, что я сделал первоначальную загрузку изображения, и также сделал плавный переход в фон, но это только статика, как это выглядит можно посмотреть [**Тут**.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/dxlamuw9)

Плавность создается с помощью градиента от непрозрачного к прозрачному, и изменения композитного режима на:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
```

То есть, отобразиться только та часть изображения, что войдет в ранее наложенный градиент.
А теперь дальше. С плавным переходом картинок все замечательно. Однако, как я не старался, у меня не получилось сделать переход изображения в фон, ни капли! Посмотреть саму динамическую смену изображений можно [**Тут**](http://tstng.vv.si). Код [**Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/ypuvCqWA). Код того что у меня получалось смысла выкладывать нет, там пару строчек, которые почти аналогичны коду для первоначальной  загрузки. Уже несколько дней эта проблема не дает мне покоя, я буду рад любой помощи и идеям!)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, пишу сюда, т.к. больше оставлять комментария под вашим ответом почему-то нельзя. Про кеширование я помню, думал сделать без зависимости от типа картинки (прозрачная/нет), но ваш вариант мне нравится) а функцию resize_canvas также перепишу с использованием кеширования. Спасибо за помощь и за то, что не брезгнули разобраться в моем коде)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм тут должен быть такой:

```
var id = window.setInterval(function() {

  /* Дефотная заливка, т.к. ниже будем менять стили, здесь восстанваливаем */
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

  /* Очистка холста не нужна, без нее и так все хорошо */

  /* Выставляем прозрачность для img1 и рисуем ее */
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - opacity;
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  /* ... img2 */
  ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  /* градиент будем лить поверх картинок и непрозрачно, он и так с необходимой прозрачностью где надо */
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;// grad - объявляем выше, достаточно одного раза
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  /*Увеличиваем прозрачность для следующей итерации таймера*/
  opacity += step;
  /* Если непрозрачность img2 достигла 1, очищаем таймер и снимаем лок*/
  if (opacity >= 1+step) {
    window.clearInterval(id);
    processing_lock = false;
  }
}, delta_time);
```

Теперь тут пара моментов:

1. Картинка img1, которую вы берете как содержимое холста (картинка с переходом), не должна содержать этот переход, иначе он будет удвоен, добавив прозрачности. В общем нужна оригинальная картинка. Кэшируйте в img1 то, что загрузилось в img2 по окончании анимации.
2. resize_canvas - вредная функция, не совсем понимаю зачем она нужна. В любом случае в ней не должно быть рисования, ибо все прозрачности она убивает - возникает эффект однократного мерцания. Если честно лень разбираться было.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, огромное спасибо за ответ, помощь в написании и пояснения. Писал код почти аналогичный вашему, но не догадался использовать использовать режим **'destination-in'**, точнее использовал, но не правильно: я наносил изображения на градиент в режиме **'source-in'**. А функция **resize_canvas** действительно вредная, прозрачность не сохраняется (и в режиме кодирования в png), но изображения могут быть разного размера, и мне важно сохранить их пропорции, буду думать чем заменить (если все-таки придется).

Comment: Переопределять **fillStyle** по 2 раза за итерацию не нужно, т.к. он не влияет на вывод изображения. А вот без предварительной очистка контекста и вправду вполне неплохо. Что получилось можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://tstng.vv.si/). Но в этой реализации одно НО: если исходная картинка на канве не имеет плавного перехода, то все это работать не будет (функция resize_canvas не может перерисовать  картинку с прозрачностью), а хотелось бы не зависеть от этого фактора. Я безумно вам благодарен за то, что уже сделали.

Comment: И прощу помочь еще раз, можно ли как-то изменить реализацию, чтобы работала с любыми изображениями? Я пробовал сначала выводить градиент, а потом, в режиме **'source-in'**, выводить на них изображения, но тогда я вообще ничего на канве не вижу.

Comment: Сейчас проблема в том, что в анимации img1.src = canvas.toDataURL() берет картинку с переходом. А должна браться исходная картинка. Иначе невооруженным глазом видно как добавляется дополнительный градиент при начале анимации.  

По поводу наложения на градиент через source-in все довольно сложно. если бы картинка была одна, все бы работало замечательно как с первоначальной картинкой, а тут накладывать две картинки приходится и если честно у меня мозга не хватает понять как там происходит взаимное складывание градиентов (притом что один из них непрозрачный и т.д.)...

Comment: Если поставить цель можно попытаться разобрать на составные части эту анимацию. сделать две канвы, нарисовать на них обе картинки потом в третью канву переложить через .toDataURL() -> .drawImage(). Не знаю, задача довольно непростая математически, плюс реализация в браузере не совсем ясная. Надо разбираться...

Comment: С 'source-in' я понял, что проблема в двойном наложении, тогда же и пришла мысль про две канвы, но думаю браузер будет тормозить, хотя черт его знает. Можно попробовать

Comment: сначала попробуйте кэшировать оригинальную картинку. т.е. .toDataURL() заменить на src по окончании анимации. Тогда наложения не будет.  
Вполне понятно, что с измененной картинкой (с переходом) работать сложнее и в плане прозрачности и в плане того как они друг на друга будут накладываться в итоге.  
А про две канвы - это для теста, чтоб разобраться как и что меняется есть ли прозрачность и т.д.

Comment: Вот ваш пример без скачков http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/N89pJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя использовать css градиенты?
Можно же просто наложить css градиент по верх картинки и получится плавный переход к цвету.